# Show that T is a vector space over C.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

Here is my try...
let $$V_1=(\alpha_1+i\beta_1)(x,y)=(\alpha_1x-\beta_1y , \beta_1x+\alpha_1y)$$
$$V_2=(\alpha_2+i\beta_2)(x,y)=(\alpha_2x-\beta_2y , \beta_2x+\alpha_2y)$$

Internal composition:

$$V_1+V_2\Rightarrow(\alpha_1+i\beta_1)(x,y)+(\alpha_2+i\beta_2)(x,y)
               \Rightarrow (\alpha_1x-\beta_1y,\beta_1x+\alpha_1y)+(\alpha_2x-\beta_2y,\beta_2x+\alpha_2y)
               \Rightarrow((\alpha_1+\alpha_2)x-(\beta_1+\beta_2)y,(\beta_1+\beta_2)x+(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)y)
                (-T(C))$$
External composition:

Let  $h+ik$ (- C and V= $(\alpha+i\beta)(x,y)= (\alpha x - \beta y , \beta x + \alpha y)$

$$(h+ik)(\alpha+i\beta)(x,y)\Rightarrow(h+ik)(\alpha x-\beta y,\beta x+\alpha y)
                       \Rightarrow (h(\alpha x-\beta y)-k(\beta x+\alpha t),k(\alpha x - \beta y)+h(\beta x+\alpha y) 
                    \Rightarrow ((h\alpha-k\beta)x-(h\beta+k\alpha)y , (k \alpha+h\beta)x + (h\alpha-k\beta)y)    
                    (- T(C))$$

Can I proceed in this way?

Comment: Sir, plz tell me why my question is not answered. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You have to describe space $T$. What is the scalar field and where are vectors drawn from.

Comment: First of all: **do you know the axioms of a vector space?** Find this list of axioms (depending on the textbook, there are between 8 to 10 of them), and verify -- one at a time! -- that each one of them is satisfied by this space $T$ (along with complex scalars) with these definitions. What you did here doesn't make much sense overall, although what you called "external composition" is pretty close to one of those axioms.

Comment: And a typesetting piece of advice. If in a formula you need to say that an element belongs to a set, use `\in` to produce $\in$. For example: `h+ik\in\mathbb{C}` produces $h+ik\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try showing that the axioms of vector spaces hold in your example:

- associativity of vector addition
- commutativity of vector addition
- distributivity of scalar multiplication over vector addition
- distributivity of scalar multiplication over scalar multiplication
- existence of vector additive identity
- existence of scalar multiplicative identity
- existence of vector additive inverse
- compatibility of scalar multiplication with field multiplication i.e. for scalars $a,b$ and vector $\mathbf {v}$, $a(b \mathbf {v}) = (ab)\mathbf {v}$